# different ttys on different monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, linux-mint, tty

I am running a few un*ces and I have now grasped the power of using different ttys (Ctrl+alt+F(x)).
Yesterday, I attached a second monitor. I was able to configure x to extend my desktop, and I became extremely pleased with the setup. Now my ambition leads me to run multiple text terminals simultaneously. Basically, perpendicular to gnu screen.
If I have 3 monitors:

(left to right)

Flatscreen tv

laptop

15 inch hp monitor

and I want to view SIMULTANEOUSLY
/dev/tty5 for irc and Instant message (finch, the ncurses implementation of libpurple

/dev/tty1 for bash, browsers, and other

/dev/tty4 for music player

From left to right.
Again, I do not want to use X for this. I want to keep this in mind in the event that I ever switch to entirely text based.
The archwiki only has multihead for x.

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding the problem is technically a solution. Make the server headless, ssh in on a different computer over 3 different monitors, use tmux to break those monitors into screens, boom, 9 windows at once.